# How to make normalized cross correlation robust to small changes in uniform regions

Tags: image-processing, statistics

the problem is described below:

Given 2 sets of data: A= {
91
87
85
85
84
90
85
83
86
86
90
86
84
89
93
87
89
91
95
97
91
92
97
101
101
},

B = {133
130
129
131
133
136
131
131
135
135
133
133
133
131
135
131
129
131
132
132
130
127
129
137
134
},

If A represent a set of pixels from a background image around (x,y) location, B represents another set of pixels around (x,y) from different image where the illumination changes.

The normalised cross correlation (NCC) calculated = 0.184138251
 (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Normalized_cross-correlation)

Calculated NCC tells us the set A is different to set B. But in fact, A and B are the same group of pixels under the different illumination conditions.

It shows that NCC is very sensitive to the small changes in the data set whose relative variation is quite small. For example, if the ratio between standard deviation and mean is representing the relative variation in each data set, then the relative variation in set A = 0.057684745, in set B = 0.018484007.

Could anyone help me to figure out how to incorporate the relative variation factor in NCC formula, so the modified NCC is robust to the small changes in data sets where the variation within each set are very small?
Also, the output of modified NCC still needs to be -1 to 1.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You might have more luck at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks, will do it to see anyone there can help me.

Comment: NCC = 0.184 looks good to me given the data. Illumination changes can range from simple ones to very complex cases, you won't be able to fully take it into consideration. What you probably want is to adjust your data before considering applying NCC, and then you need a different question that is more detailed in that point.

Comment: Your data set A and B look quit different. Try to plot A and B and you will see difference. So calculation of NCC give valid result.

Comment: The variation is caused by the camera noise and illumination. I know NCC is valid but it can not handle the small variations if the inherent variance within each data set is small. Both the relative variation in set A = 0.057684745, in set B = 0.018484007. (Note both data set A and set B belongs to the same group of pixel under different illumination.

Comment: @song The problem is not different illumination but big camera noise. The level of noise is comparable with difference from max to min in your data. If you reduce noise NCC will be work quite well with variation of illumination.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. being robust to noise
2. being robust to illumination changes.

For noise robustness, I would suggest you to apply some denoising algorithm. Depending on your application, computational constraints, knowledge... you can try a simple median filtering, or more complicated bilateral filtering or non-local means. Each of these algorithms will preserve most of the fine structures of your images (which ar eimportant for the NCC).

Then, to be robust against illumination changes, you can start with applying a simple histogram matching procedure first. If it does not work well enough you should give a try to the [Midway algorithm](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/~delon/Pdf/2004_Midway_Image_Equalization_JMIV.pdf) (pdf) that was developed by Julie Delon specifically for this case of stereo matching. It is relatively easy to implement (I did it in a few hours using OpenCV/C++).

Answer (score 0):

Normalizing images before the correlation may help!
if you have a choice I suggest you to test the phase correlation 
[here](http://www.ee.oulu.fi/mvg/files/pdf/acivs08-bcifsm.pdf) you find a very interesting paper
I hope that helps